# Create an interactive program that asks the user to provide a string, a char, an int, and a floating point value. Answers print on different lines

Tags: java, character, interactive

```
 
class Interactive {
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Please enter your height in feet: ");
        final String s = console.next();
        System.out.println ("Please enter a character: ");
        final char c = console.nextChar();
        System.out.println ("Please enter your age: ");
        final int i = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("Please enter your weight in lbs: ");
        final float f = console.nextFloat();
        System.out.println ("Your height is: " + s);
        System.out.println ("Your character is: " + c);
        System.out.println ("Your age is: " + i);
        System.out.println ("Your weight is: " + f);
    }
}
```

How would I go about adding char? When I add `final char c = console.nextChar();` it gives me an error. Thanks for your help.

**The error:** Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project JavaExercise: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: What error does it give you? Also, are you sure you want to use `nextInt()` when asking for a float?

Comment: I changed it to `nextFloat();` and added the error in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to take a char input directly using a Scanner.  However, here is a little work around:

```
final String s1 = console.next();
final char c = s1.charAt(0);
```

The only problem with this code is that you could type in more than one character, but if you know you're only going to input one character it shouldn't be an issue.  If you type in more than one character, it would print only the first one that is inputed.